# aframe taking a screenshot freezes camera

Tags: aframe

I'm taking a screenshot as such

```
scene.setAttribute('screenshot',{width: 1024, height: 1024})
const imgData = scene.components.screenshot.getCanvas('perspective')
```

This works, but aftwards the scene is unresponsive and look controls no longer work on the camera.

Is there something that needs to be done to restore the camera?

Comment: Provide link with code to reproduce so people can help you. glitch.com/~aframe will do

Comment: There’s a PR that addresses the issue: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4169